# Fiware Orion - pepProxy

Tags: fiware-orion

i'm part of a team that is developing an application that uses the Fiware GE's has part of the Smart-AgriFood accelerator.
We are using the Orion Context Broker for gathering the data provided by the sensor network, and we intend to use the Pep-Proxy to authenticate the sensor node for access the Orion instance. We have tried the following pepProxy's:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep

https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy

We only have success implementing the second (*fi-ware-pep-proxy*) implementation of the proxy. With the *fiware-orion-pep* we haven't been able to connect to the Keystone Global instance (account.lab.fi-ware.org), we have tried the *account.lab...* and the *cloud.lab...*, my question are:

1) is the keystone (IDM) instance for authentication the account.lab or the cloud.lab?? and what port's to use or address's?

2) is the fiware-orion-pep prepared for authenticate at the account.lab.fi-ware.org?? here is way i ask this:

This one works with the curl command at  >> cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v2.0/tokens

```
{
    "auth": {
        "passwordCredentials": {

                   "username": "<my_user>",
                    "password": "<my_password>"
                }
            }
}'
```

This one does't work with the curl comand at >> account.lab.fi-ware.org:5000/v3/auth/tokens

```
{
    "auth": {
        "identity": {
            "methods": [
                "password"
            ],
            "password": {
                "user": {
                    "domain": {
                        "name": "<my_domain>"
                    },
                    "name": "<my_user>",
                    "password": "<my_password>"
                }
            }
        }
    } }'
```

3) what is the implementation that i should be using for authenticate the devices or other calls to the Orion instance???

Here are the configuration that i used:

*fiware-orion-pep*

```
config.authentication = {
    checkHeaders: true,
    module: 'keystone',
    user: '<my_user>',
    password: '<my_password>',
    domainName: '<my_domain>',
    retries: 3,
    cacheTTLs: {
        users: 1000,
        projectIds: 1000,
        roles: 60
    },
    options: {
        protocol: 'http',
        host: 'account.lab.fiware.org',
        port: 5000,
        path: '/v3/role_assignments',
        authPath: '/v3/auth/tokens'
    }
};
```

*fi-ware-pep-proxy (this one works), i have set the listing port to 1026 at the source code*

```
var config = {};

config.account_host = 'https://account.lab.fiware.org';

config.keystone_host = 'cloud.lab.fiware.org';
config.keystone_port = 4731;

config.app_host = 'localhost';
config.app_port = '10026';

config.username = 'pepProxy';
config.password = 'pepProxy';

// in seconds
config.chache_time = 300;
config.check_permissions = false;

config.magic_key = undefined;

module.exports = config;
```

Thanks in advance for the time ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are currently some differences in how both PEP Proxies authenticate and validate against the global instances, so they do not behave in exactly the same way.

The one in telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep was developed to fulfill the PEP Proxy requirements (authentication and validation against a Keystone and Access Control) in individual projects with their own Keystone and Keypass (a flavour of Access Control) installations, and so it evolved faster than the one in ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy and in a slightly different direction. As an example, the former supports multitenancy using the fiware-service and fiware-servicepath headers, while the latter is transparent to those mechanisms. This development direction meant also that the functionality slightly differs from time to time from the one in the global instance.

That being said, the concrete answer:
- Both PEP Proxies should be able to contact the global instance. If one doesn't, please, fill a bug in the issues of the Github repository and we will fix it as soon as possible.
- The ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy was specifically designed for accessing the global instance, so you should be able to use it as expected.

Please, if you try to proceed with the telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep take note also that:
- the configuration flag authentication.checkHeaders should be false, as the global instance does not currently support multitenancy. 
- current stable release (0.5.0) is about to change to next version (probably today) so maybe some of the problems will solve with the update.

Hope this clarify some of your doubts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Daniel , i will tray later today to update the telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep and test if we can authenticate against the Keystone Global instance.
At the end of the day a will give my feedback regarding the test.
Again thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: I have done some test with the version 0.6.0 of the telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep. What have i done:

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

1) I have already install the telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep (v 0.6.0) from sources and from the rpm package created following the tutorial available in the github. When creating the rpm package, this is created with the following name pep-proxy-0.4.0_next-0.noarch.rpm.

2) Here is the configuration that i used:

> > /opt/fiware-orion-pep/config.js

```
 var config = {};
 config.resource = {
     original: {
         host: 'localhost', 
         port: 10026
     },
     proxy: { 
        port: 1026,
        adminPort: 11211
     } }; 

 config.authentication = {
     checkHeaders: false,
     module: 'keystone',
     user: '<##################>',
     password: '<###################>',
     domainName: 'admin_domain',
     retries: 3,
     cacheTTLs: {
         users: 1000,
         projectIds: 1000,
         roles: 60
     },
     options: {     protocol: 'http',
         host: 'cloud.lab.fiware.org',
         port: 4730,
         path: '/v3/role_assignments',
         authPath: '/v3/auth/tokens'
     } };  

 config.ssl = {
     active: false,
     keyFile: '',
     certFile: '' }

 config.logLevel = 'DEBUG'; // List of component
 config.middlewares = {
     require: 'lib/plugins/orionPlugin',
     functions: [
         'extractCBAction'
     ] };

 config.componentName = 'orion'; 
 config.resourceNamePrefix = 'fiware:';

 config.bypass = false;

 config.bypassRoleId = '';

 module.exports = config;
```

> > /etc/sysconfig/pepProxy

```
# General Configuration
############################################################################

# Port where the proxy will listen for requests
PROXY_PORT=1026

# User to execute the PEP Proxy with
PROXY_USER=pepproxy

# Host where the target Context Broker is located
# TARGET_HOST=localhost

# Port where the target Context Broker is listening
# TARGET_PORT=10026

# Maximum level of logs to show (FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG)
LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG

# Indicates what component plugin should be loaded with this PEP: orion, keypass, perseo
COMPONENT_PLUGIN=orion

#
# Access Control Configuration
############################################################################

# Host where the Access Control (the component who knows the policies for the incoming requests) is located
# ACCESS_HOST=

# Port where the Access Control is listening
# ACCESS_PORT=

# Host where the authentication authority for the Access Control is located
# AUTHENTICATION_HOST=

# Port where the authentication authority is listening
# AUTHENTICATION_PORT=

# User name of the PEP Proxy in the authentication authority
PROXY_USERNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXX

# Password of the PEP Proxy in the Authentication authority
PROXY_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In the files above i have tried the following parameters:

Keystone instance: account.lab.fiware.org or cloud.lab.fiware.org

User: pep or pepProxy or "user from fiware account"

Pass: pep or pepProxy or "user password from account"

Port: 4730, 4731, 5000

The result it's the same as before... the telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep is unable to authenticate:

```
log file at /var/log/pepProxy/pepProxy
time=2015-04-13T14:49:24.718Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=71a34c8b-10b3-40a3-be85-71bd3ce34c8a | trans=71a34c8b-10b3-40a3-be85-71bd3ce34c8a | op=/v1/updateContext | msg=VALIDATION-GEN-003] Error connecting to Keystone authentication: KEYSTONE_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR: There was a connection error while authenticating to Keystone: 500
time=2015-04-13T14:49:24.721Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=71a34c8b-10b3-40a3-be85-71bd3ce34c8a | trans=71a34c8b-10b3-40a3-be85-71bd3ce34c8a | op=/v1/updateContext | msg=response-time: 50745 statusCode: 500
```

result from the client console

```
{
    "message": "There was a connection error while authenticating to Keystone: 500", 
    "name": "KEYSTONE_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR"
}
```

I'm doing something wrong here??

Comment: First of all, regarding the RPM version, we have a problem with the release script, and I'm afraid that's a bug. I'm making a quick patch for the script right now.

Comment: Concerning the rest of the post, the problem is we haven't tested our PEP against the new Global instance yet (we are using it with private Keystone instances, that we can easily debug). Either way, I'm going to contact the people in the Security Chapter to retrieve some information about how the Global Keystone is configured, and why it may be failing. Stay tuned.

Comment: By the way, the create-rpm.sh script can be executed with two parameters <release> and <version> that will generate the appropriate RPM name. The bug is in the documentation. I'm changing that instead of the script.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMoránJiménez for the reply :)
I will wait for more information regarding the authentication process against the new Global Instance, until there i will be using the "fi-ware-pep-proxy" instance. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear @af-silva, I know is been awhile since you faced this problem, but I was wondering if you could give any feedback to my post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808743/setting-up-pep-proxy) since apparently I'm facing a quite similar issues as you did. Thanks in advance.